# Traverse json object to print root to children path separeted by dot

Tags: python, json

so coming straight to the problem. I have some json object as below.

```
{
"root": {
    "Child": {
        "subChild": 10,
        "subChild2": 20
    },
    "Child2": {
        "subChild2": 20,
        "subChild3": 500
    }
}
```

}

and I wanted to print the output like:

```
[root.Child.subChild,
root.Child.subChild2],

[root.Child2.subChild2,
root.Child2.subChild3]
```

The json object can have multiple nested levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
def json_as_dotted_path(obj, path=''):
    result = []
    for key, value in obj.iteritems():
        new_path = path + '.'  + key if path else key
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result.extend(json_as_dotted_path(value, path=new_path))
        else:
            result.append(new_path)
    return result

json = {
    "root": {
        "Child": {
            "subChild": 10,
            "subChild2": 20
        },
        "Child2": {
            "subChild2": 20,
            "subChild3": 500
        }

    }
}

from pprint import pprint

pprint(json_as_dotted_path(json))
```

Which will output:

```
['root.Child2.subChild3',
 'root.Child2.subChild2',
 'root.Child.subChild',
 'root.Child.subChild2']
```

It may not cover all corner cases, but that should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: what does "key if path else key" means here?

Comment: ok I found now what "key if path else key" means. how stupid I was to ask this!

Comment: In case someone else has the same question: that's a ternary expression. It's saying to set `new_path` to the value of `path + '.'  + key` if the `path` variable contains a Truthy value. otherwise set `new_path` to the value of  `key`. I'm preventing the root node from being prefixed with "."

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but this answer saved me some time today. I added to OozMeisters answer a little to deal with lists within the JSON. It may help someone.

```py
    def json_as_dotted_path(obj, path=''):
    try:
        result = []
        for key, value in obj.items():
            new_path = path + '.'  + key if path else key
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                result.extend(json_as_dotted_path(value, path=new_path))
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                new_path = new_path + '[0]'
                if isinstance(value[0], str):
                    result.append(new_path)
                else:
                    result.extend(json_as_dotted_path(value[0], path=new_path))    
            else:
                result.append(new_path)
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        if key: print(key)
        if value: print(value)
```

It will add a [0] to the path to indicate the presence of a list and continue looking at objects within the list.

Example output

```json
    ['authority',
    'date'.
    'rule.description',
    'rule.date',
    'school.notices[0].subject',
    'school.notices[0].staff[0]',
    'school.notices[0].staff[0].name'
    'school.notices[0].staff[0].classroom']
```